# Elasticsearch: filter by max field value in a given mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

**About this Elasticsearch mapping**

```
PUT /some-index/_mapping/some-mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "group-id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "some-other-field": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

**Lets say we have values such as these**

```
[
  { "group-id": "1", "id": "1", "some-other-field": "some" },
  { "group-id": "2", "id": "2", "some-other-field": "other" },
  { "group-id": "2", "id": "3", "some-other-field": "field" }
]
```

**Trying to build a query**

Return all records with largest *group-id*. In this specific example, it should exactly return the last 2 items including *id* and *some-other-field*. Of course, the largest *group-id* could get bigger as new records get indexed. If that occurs, a completely new set of results should be returned as the previous ones wouldn't contain the largest *group-id* anymore.

Comment: does this "[
  { "group-id": "1", "id": "1", "some-other-field": "some" },
  { "group-id": "2", "id": "2", "some-other-field": "other" },
  { "group-id": "2", "id": "3", "some-other-field": "field" }
]", is single elastic documents, is it nested field?

Comment: They are 3 different documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support by a largest ID, you should change the type of your fields to a number.

You could use a `max` aggregation to find out the maximum value first (if this is a numeric field), and then execute a second query, searching for all documents with that maximum value (dont be afraid to execute more than one query to answer your question, it is perfectly fine).

Comment: So you say there is no way to do this in one call?

Comment: indeed, not on top of my head.

Comment: That's what I was in the process of figuring out, hence the question... Feels weird though that such a basic functionality isn't available in such a powerful tool. Thanks for the help!